# Angular Filter on a computed property?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use $filter on a calculated property and it does not appear to work. I have not been able to find any similar examples and have tried everything I can think of.

Here is the controller:

```
    function PriceAnalyticsCtrl($scope, $filter, products, productService) {
    var vm = $scope;

    vm.title = "Price Analytics";

    // Computed property
    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++)
    {
        products[i].marginPercent = function () {
            return productService.calculateMarginPercent(products[i].price, products[i].cost);
        };
        products[i].marginAmount = function () {
            return productService.calculateMarginAmount(products[i].price, products[i].cost);
        };
    };

    var orderedProducts = $filter('orderBy')(products, 'marginPercent');

}
```

I am first adding two computed properties. I am then ordering by one of them.

Is there a way to order by a calculated property?
Thanks!

Comment: Are your products actually showing up in the ng-repeat? I don't see them assigned to the scope or anything.

Comment: I'm not using an ng-repeat. After organizing the data, it is reformatted for display in a chart. That required lots of code that was not relevant to the problem, so I excluded it from the pasted code.

Comment: I just added a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4r5K5/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter parameter requires an angular expression. So currently it's looking for a property, and in this case, it is returning a function instead of the evaluation of the function. 
Try:

```
var orderedProducts = $filter('orderBy')(products, 'marginPercent()');
```

Comment: Yes, I had tried that early on. But that results in a syntax error: "Unable to get property 'price' of undefined or null reference" Maybe I'm not defining the computer properties properly?

Comment: OK. I was able to get this to work by changing the computed properties to actually be a property and not a function. The working fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/4r5K5/9/ Thanks for your help!